# I want to return something and execute some other method. Is there any way in JAVA?

Tags: java, return, void

I am a beginner at Java.
So I have a question.

I have a method:

```
public boolean method1() {
    if (something) {
        returnVal = true;
    } else {
        returnVal = false;
        method2();
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

I realize that after the second condition is true, even though it will set returnVal to false, it won't return because it will further execute method2(). Is there any way to refactor my code so that whichever condition is true, my method1 returns returnVal.

Thanks.

Comment: user2262292, Welcome to StackOverflow! Since you're new to the site you may want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method *will* return `false`. Just after `method2` has finished.

There's no way to force a method to be called *after* you've returned. (Even if there was a way to achieve that, it wouldn't make sense. If `method2` should be called before the caller of `method1` could execute anything, it would be the same as calling `method2` before returning.)

Since you ask however, you could execute the return statement before calling `method2` (sort of) as follows:

```
try {
    return false;
} finally {
    method2();
}
```

but that's semantically equivalent to what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

> it won't return because it will further execute `method2()`

Why?

Yes, it will return **after** you have executed `method2()`, but is that a problem? As soon as `method2()` is complete, then `method1()` will return false.

If you want to return and then do the method, then you will need to do it in another thread (which is probably unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

Your method will return false after `method2()` runs.

If you wanted to use the return value of `method1()` in order to decide if you wanted to run `method2()`, you can write the code like so:

```
if (!method1()) {
    method2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if method2 redirects or closes something then the false will not return, what does method2 do?
it should finish method2 then come back to method1 and returns false unless method2 does something to the returnVal making it true.

also, you could just return true or false rather than setting up a variable to return:

```
public boolean method1() 
{
   if (something) 
   {
      return true;
   }
   else 
   {
    method2();
    return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want something like this?

```js
public boolean method1() {
  if (something) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
  method2();//This will be dead code
}
```

or like this?

```js
public boolean method1() {
 if (something) {
      return true;
}
 else {
   try
     {
    return false; //first return false
       }
   finally
     {
    method2();//then call this
       }
}
}
```

Comment: your first snippet doesn't even compile.